# Icon for snap store suddenly changed

Tags: icon-themes, snap-store

Ubuntu 23.10. I was changing the icon theme in `$HOME/.local/share/icons`. Everything works fine until suddenly snap-store's icon is changed to this:

[image]

The content of /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/snap-store_snap-store.desktop is

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-SnapInstanceName=snap-store
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/snap-store_snap-store.desktop /snap/bin/snap-store %U
Icon=/snap/snap-store/1106/bin/data/flutter_assets/assets/app-center.png
Terminal=false
Categories=System;Utility;PackageManager;SoftwareManagement;Network;Settings;
Keywords=Ubuntu;Applications;Apps;Store;Software;Snaps;
Name=App Center
Name[ar]=مركز التطبيقات
Name[cs]=Centrum aplikací
Name[de]=Anwendungszentrum
Name[en_CA]=App Center
Name[en_GB]=App Center
Name[es]=Centro de aplicaciones
Name[fr]=Centre d'applications
Name[hi]=ऐप सेंटर
Name[ja]=アプリセンター
Name[pl]=Centrum programów
Name[pt_BR]=Centro de Aplicações
Name[ru]=Центр приложений
Name[sk]=Centrum aplikácií
Name[sv]=Appcentral
Name[zh_CN]=应用中心
```

The `/snap/snap-store/1106/bin/data/flutter_assets/assets/app-center.png` file matches with the above image. However, this is not the original icon before the icon theme change.

I cannot revert to the default icon by changing the icon theme to Yaru for example.

I also tried restarting the computer, but nothing worked.

How should this happen? I didn't do anything with sudo privileges.

The default should look like this

[image]

I can modify the Icon field to `Icon=snap-store`. It's a little hacking and it works. However, with this change, the Yaru icon theme will look like this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `rm -rf ~/.local/share/mime ~/.local/share/.icons ~/.cache` and rebooting?

Comment: Still no effect. Since I have only 2 Snap applications installed, I am considering completely removing Snap.

Comment: You might as well do that — back up and reinstall snap